Splitting up the Log Files in Log4j2?
I currently have a "LocalLogger" Class that handles all my logging stuff. I can make a new Object of that class in my other classes, to maintain the same logging all over.
Currently the LocalLogger Class, makes 2 Log Files. InfoLog and ErrorLog.
My Problem is, that the Logger is writing every Log from different Classes in 1 Log File. That is in general not a problem, and it is the way i want it. BUT he is writing it in the wrong File.
This is my Logger Class:
public class LocalLogger {

    private final Logger logger;
    private final Logger elogger;
    private final Logger ilogger;

    private final Class<?> logClass;

    private Configuration config;
    private final Date startTime;


    public LocalLogger(Configuration config, Class<?> logClass) {
        this.config = config;
        this.logClass = logClass;
        this.startTime = new Date();

        configureLogger();
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(logClass);
        elogger = LogManager.getLogger("errorLogger");
        ilogger = LogManager.getLogger("infoLogger");

        logInfo("Starting Time: " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm:ss").format(startTime));
        logInfo("ErrorLogFile set to -> " + config.getErrorLogFile());
    }


    public LocalLogger(Class<?> logClass) {
        this.logClass = logClass;
        this.startTime = new Date();

        configureLogger();
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(logClass);
        elogger = LogManager.getLogger("errorLogger");
        ilogger = LogManager.getLogger("infoLogger");

        logInfo("Starting Time: " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm:ss").format(startTime));
    }

    private void configureLogger() {
        String infoLog = config != null && config.getLogFile() != null && !config.getLogFile().isEmpty() ? config.getLogFile() : logClass.getSimpleName() + "-INFO.log";
        String errorLog = config != null && config.getErrorLogFile() != null && !config.getLogFile().isEmpty() ? config.getErrorLogFile() : logClass.getSimpleName() + "-ERROR.log";
        String logLevel = config != null && config.getLogLevel() != null && !config.getLogLevel().isEmpty() ? config.getLogLevel() : "INFO";


        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

        builder.setStatusLevel(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN);
        builder.setConfigurationName("DynamicConfig");

        LayoutComponentBuilder standard
                = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout");
        standard.addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable");


        AppenderComponentBuilder consoleAppender = builder.newAppender("Console", "Console")
                .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        consoleAppender.add(standard);
        builder.add(consoleAppender);


        AppenderComponentBuilder fileInfoAppender = builder.newAppender("InfoFile", "File")
                .addAttribute("fileName", infoLog)
                .addAttribute("append", "true");
        fileInfoAppender.add(standard);
        fileInfoAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.TRACE));
        builder.add(fileInfoAppender);


        AppenderComponentBuilder fileErrorAppender = builder.newAppender("ErrorFile", "File")
                .addAttribute("fileName", errorLog)
                .addAttribute("append", "true");
        fileErrorAppender.add(standard);
        fileErrorAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN));
        builder.add(fileErrorAppender);


        RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR);
        rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Console"));
        builder.add(rootLogger);

        LoggerComponentBuilder errorLogger = builder.newLogger("errorLogger", Level.WARN);
        errorLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("ErrorFile"));
        builder.add(errorLogger);

        LoggerComponentBuilder infoLogger = builder.newLogger("infoLogger", Level.TRACE);
        infoLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("InfoFile"));
        builder.add(infoLogger);

        LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
    }

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logTrace(String message) {
        ilogger.trace(message);
    } // trace

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logDebug(String message) {
        ilogger.debug(message);
    } // debug

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logInfo(String message) {
        ilogger.info(message);
    } // info

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logWarning(String message) {
        elogger.warn(message);
    } // warn



    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logError(String message) {
        elogger.error(message);
    } // error

    /**
     * Handles truncated stack trace logging via Log4j Logging
     *
     * @param key unique String value (e.g. file path)
     * @param message individual log message
     * @param exception the exception to log with max stack trace length
     *
     */
    public void logSevere(String key, String message, Exception exception) {
        //TODO special exception Handling?

        String msg = key + ":" + message;

        elogger.fatal(msg);
    } // fatal
}

This is a Constructor of one of my other classes:
public Exporter(File adminConfig, String jsonString, Date startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;

        JSONToConfigXML configBuilder = new JSONToConfigXML(jsonString, adminConfig);
        File completeConfig = configBuilder.parse();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        Map<String, Object> configMap = parser.parse(completeConfig);
        ExportConfiguration cfg = new ExportConfiguration();
        cfg.setConfigFile(completeConfig.getAbsolutePath());

        initConfig(cfg, configMap);
        this.config = cfg;
        this.logger = new LocalLogger(this.config, Exporter.class);
    }

This is just the simple execute main class:
private static final LocalLogger logger = new LocalLogger(ExporterMain.class);
    private static final Date startTime = new Date();
    
    /**
     * @param args - Config File
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length < 1) {
                System.out.println("Usage: java ExporterMain <filename>");
                System.exit(1);
            } else {
                
                File config = new File(args[0]);

                Exporter exp = new Exporter(config, startTime);
                exp.execute();

                System.out.println("SuccessCounter: "+ exp.getSuccessCounter());
                System.out.println("ErrorCounter: "+ exp.getErrorCounter());
                System.out.println("LastItem: "+ exp.getLastItem());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.logSevere("exec", e.getMessage(), e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

Currently he writes 6 Log Files: 2 for ExporterMain, 2 for XMLParser and 2 for Exporter.
Atm he is writing every log in the ExporterMain Log Files. But in this case i want to have all Logs written to the Exporter Log, because there is a log-path in the config which i want to use.
He is creating the File in the right directory from the path in the config, but the files are empty.

Your comments are a bit confusing. You need to clarify your problem That is in general not a problem, and it is the way i want it. BUT he is writing it in the wrong File. if it is not a problem then why is it an issue?

Programmatic configuration is difficult to get right. If you are trying to do what I think you want to do, I would recommend against it. What you should do instead is to initialize your configuration once only and to use a RoutingAppender, use those config values as markers to route based on those markers to a file appender which changes the name of the file based on the marker provided

This question is similar to: How to Dynamically log when iterating in a filepath and reading the contents of file How to create separate log file for each file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I want to have only 2 Log Files, for one operation. So instead of having 2 for XMLParser, ExporterMain and Exporter, i only want to have the InfoLog and ErrorLog for Exporter, in which every log stands. Currently it is like this, but all the logs are in the ExporterMain Log File and not in the one configured via config from Exporter. So how do i get all Logs in the Log File configured in the Exporter Config, instead of the Class where i have my main method (ExporterMain)

if all of it is added to ExporterMain, is there a point to writing 6 log files? just change the name of the log file to something generic like exporter-info.log or exporter-error.log and call it a day. Though I personally think that using the RoutingAppender and writing 6 log files each with their own correct respective logs is the way to go.

Yes, i dont want to create 6 log files, but i cant change the name to something static because i need to get it dynamically from the config.
String infoLog = config != null && config.getLogFile() != null && !config.getLogFile().isEmpty() ? config.getLogFile() : logClass.getSimpleName() + "-INFO.log";
As u can see here.
But for every instance (XMLParser and ExporterMain and Exporter) he creates new FIles. But i only want 2 files which get created by the config-settings.

You can take an approach similar to this - provide a default configuration (you can use a config file (log4j2.xml etc.) for this, or programmatic as follows) that is initialized once only that will do logging for any loggers that you do not provide a config file for. Then, on demand, create new loggers and update the context as needed (when you want to create loggers with some user defined property.
public class misc {
    private final Logger logger;
    private final Logger elogger;
    private final Logger ilogger;

    static {
        String infoLog = "infoLog.log";
        String errorLog = "errorLog.log";
        String logLevel = "TRACE";


        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

        builder.setStatusLevel(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN);
        builder.setConfigurationName("DynamicConfig");

        LayoutComponentBuilder standard
                = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout");
        standard.addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable");


        AppenderComponentBuilder consoleAppender = builder.newAppender("Console", "Console")
                .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        consoleAppender.add(standard);
        builder.add(consoleAppender);


        AppenderComponentBuilder fileInfoAppender = builder.newAppender("InfoFile", "File")
                .addAttribute("fileName", infoLog)
                .addAttribute("append", "true");
        fileInfoAppender.add(standard);
        fileInfoAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.INFO));
        builder.add(fileInfoAppender);


        AppenderComponentBuilder fileErrorAppender = builder.newAppender("ErrorFile", "File")
                .addAttribute("fileName", errorLog)
                .addAttribute("append", "true");
        fileErrorAppender.add(standard);
        fileErrorAppender.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                .addAttribute("level", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN));
        builder.add(fileErrorAppender);


        RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.getLevel(logLevel));
        rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Console"));
        builder.add(rootLogger);

        var errorLogger = builder.newLogger("errorLogger", Level.WARN);
        errorLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("ErrorFile"));
        builder.add(errorLogger);

        var infoLogger = builder.newLogger("infoLogger", Level.INFO);
        infoLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("InfoFile"));
        builder.add(infoLogger);

        var ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
    }

    public misc() {
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(this);
        elogger = LogManager.getLogger("errorLogger");
        ilogger = LogManager.getLogger("infoLogger");
    }

    public misc(String configInfo, String configError) {
        configureAndAppendLogger(configInfo, configError);
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(this);
        elogger = LogManager.getLogger(configError);
        ilogger = LogManager.getLogger(configInfo);
    }

    private synchronized void configureAndAppendLogger(String infoLog, String errorLog) {
        final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
//        var loggers = config.getLoggers();

        Layout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withPattern("%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable").build();

        Appender infoAppender = FileAppender.newBuilder().withName(infoLog).withFileName("./csv/"+infoLog).withAppend(true)
                .setConfiguration(config).setLayout(layout).build();
        AppenderRef infoRef = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("File", null, null);
        AppenderRef[] infoRefs = new AppenderRef[] {infoRef};
        infoAppender.start();
        config.addAppender(infoAppender);
        var newInfoLogger = LoggerConfig.newBuilder().withLoggerName(infoLog).withConfig(config)
                .withAdditivity(true).withLevel(Level.valueOf("info")).withIncludeLocation("true")
                .withProperties(null).withRefs(infoRefs).withtFilter(null).build();
        newInfoLogger.addAppender(infoAppender, null, null);
        config.addLogger(infoLog, newInfoLogger);

        Appender errorAppender = FileAppender.newBuilder().withName(errorLog).withFileName("./csv/"+errorLog).withAppend(true)
                .setConfiguration(config).setLayout(layout).build();
        AppenderRef errorRef = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("File", null, null);
        AppenderRef[] errorRefs = new AppenderRef[] {errorRef};
        errorAppender.start();
        config.addAppender(errorAppender);
        var newErrorLogger = LoggerConfig.newBuilder().withLoggerName(errorLog).withConfig(config)
                .withAdditivity(true).withLevel(Level.valueOf("warn")).withIncludeLocation("true")
                .withProperties(null).withRefs(errorRefs).withtFilter(null).build();
        newErrorLogger.addAppender(errorAppender, null, null);
        config.addLogger(errorLog, newErrorLogger);

        ctx.updateLoggers();
    }

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logInfo(String message) {
        ilogger.info(message);
    } // info

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logWarning(String message) {
        elogger.warn(message);
    } // warn

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logFine(String message) {
        logger.debug(message);
    } // debug

    /**
     * Redirection to Log4j Logger.
     *
     * @param message message to log
     */
    public void logFinest(String message) {
        logger.trace(message);
    } // debug

    /**
     * Handles truncated stack trace logging via Log4j Logging
     *
     * @param key unique String value (e.g. file path)
     * @param message individual log message
     * @param exception the exception to log with max stack trace length
     *
     */
    public void logSevere(String key, String message, Exception exception) {
        //TODO special exception Handling?

        String msg = key + ":" + message;

        elogger.fatal(msg);
    } // error
}

This does not avoid the problem of having multiple log files, but will at least separate the logging to the correct log files. I tested it as follows:
public class Main {
//    private static final misc m = new misc();

//    static {
//        m.logInfo("static info");
//        m.logWarning("static warning");
//    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        misc misc = new misc("testInfo.log", "testErr.log");
        misc.logFine("fine");
        misc.logInfo("info");
        misc.logWarning("warning");

        misc misc2 = new misc("secondInfo.log", "secondErr.log");
        misc2.logFine("fine");
        misc2.logInfo("info");
        misc2.logWarning("warning");
    }
}

but for some reason even though no logging was done to the default log files, it will still create the log files but will be empty.
